# Ubuntu 22.04 OpenVpn server error: write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I start openvpn server with `openvpn --dev tun --ifconfig 172.16.0.1 172.16.0.2 --cipher AES-256-CBC` on my Ubuntu 22.04 Linux Box

I generate the certificates and keys with easycert and copy everything on a Windows 10 client.

The connection doesn't work, and in the syslog I find a lot of

```
write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
write to TUN/TAP : Invalid argument (code=22)
...
```

What's wrong? This is my client configuration file:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote *MYSERVERIP* 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that your server uses `comp-lzo adaptive` compression default (even if not added to the `server.conf` file), but client does not have compression enabled at all. So the client is sending uncompressed packets, while the server is expecting a compression header. Pls check a log: `/var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log`  on your server.
To solve the problem pls add this line: `comp-lzo adaptive`  or simply `comp-lzo`  to your `client.conf` file, because  `adaptive`  is the default mode for `comp-lzo`, so you can omit that.
You can also add the same option to your `server.conf` file, then you are sure that your server uses the same kind of compression.

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you have a vpn configuration file like .pcf:

1)convert the file format to .conf:
$>pcf2vpnc file.pcf file.conf

2)so you can connect by typing:
$>vpnc ./file.conf

3)and disconnect:
$> vpnc-disconnect

I found this in: https://kifarunix.com/connect-to-cisco-vpn-using-pcf-file-on-ubuntu/